# Dynamic ng-model binding inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a custom component that uses a dynamic ng-model inside-out the directive.

As an example, I could invoke different components like:

```
<custom-dir ng-model="domainModel1"></custom-dir>
<custom-dir ng-model="domainModel2"></custom-dir>
```

With a directive like:

```
app.directive('customDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=dirValue',
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="dirValue" />',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.dirValue = 'New';
    }
  };
});
```

The idea is that the textbox from the directive would change if the model changes, and in the other way around.

The thing is that I've tried different approaches with no success at all, you can check one of this here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7MzDJsP8ZJ59nASjz31g?p=preview In this example, I'm expecting to have the value 'New' in both of the inputs, since I'm changing the model from the directive and is a bi-directional bound (=). But somehow is not bound in the right way. :(

I will be really grateful if someone give some light on that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/bateast/RJmhB/1/

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <my-dir ng-model="test"></my-dir>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '='
            },
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel"></div>',            
        };
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Have you been able to make error messages work for an input inside a directive template? Thanks.

Comment: What if I use `scope: false`? Because I don't want my directive to have its own scope in this case.

Comment: Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0770zbft/). All I did was to switch `scope` to `false`, that is `scope: false`