# Why won't the model be updated in this recursive Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive, scope, angular-ngmodel

This has been baffling me all day.

Why won't the names update when I type in the text fields? Everything is by the book. What could be going wrong?

To summarize: I'm trying build a recursive directive that when it encounters an object, it calls itself again until it gets down to the string level. When it does, it gives an input that can alter the string (aka the value of the key/value in the object)

#### [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdbkv3p9/1/)

```
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <my-dir the-model="greet"></my-dir>{{greet}}</div>
</body>

angular.module('test', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greet = {
        "name": "Joe",
        "surname": "Norris"
    };
})
    .directive('myDir', function ($compile) {
        var theTemplate = 
            '<div ng-if="isObject(theModel)">' +
                    '<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in theModel">'+
                        '<my-dir the-model="theModel[key]"></my-dir>'+
                    '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div ng-if="!isObject(theModel)">' +
                '<input type="text" ng-model="theModel">'+
            '</div>'
        
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            theModel: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.isObject = function (val) {
                if (typeof val === 'object') {
                    console.log("isObject");
                    return true;
                } else{
                    console.log("is not Object");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
    link: function (scope, element) {
        element.html(theTemplate); //.append(theTemplate);
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: don't use primitives in `ng-model`. There is no inheritance for primitives. rule of thumb ... `ng-model` should always have a dot in it

Comment: @charlietfl so what should I use? And what do you mean `ng-model`s should have a dot in it?

Comment: Read up on angular scopes and specifically inheritance within scopes

Comment: I don't understand how it works here but not by me http://stackoverflow.com/a/20672965/1675976

Comment: different situation regarding child scopes and reccursion

Comment: @charlietfl its all about typo in template, he putted `key` instead of `k` inside template html `the-model` attribute

Answer (score 0):

when we provide `ng-model` with a `variable name`, `ng-model` will update the variable in the scope with which it is compiled.

`ng-repeat` creates a new Scope for **every iteration**.

When we use `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat`, each `ng-model` will be compiled with the new scope created by ng-repeat. Hence these values are not updated in the controller's scope.

To update the value in the controller's scope use dot notation. (i.e, create an object in controller and bind ng-model to the properties of it)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with directive template in which you made one mistake (**typo**)

You should changed `the-model` attribute value from `theModel[key]` to `theModel[k]` because you declared `(k,v)` which are key value pair inside `ng-repeat`.

**Template**

```
var theTemplate =
    '<div ng-if="isObject(theModel)">' +
      '<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in theModel">' +
        '<my-dir the-model="theModel[k]"></my-dir>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div ng-if="!isObject(theModel)">' +
        '<input type="text" ng-model="theModel">' +
    '</div>'
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdbkv3p9/3/)**

Hope this could help you, Thanks.